# how to allow docker nginx webdav writing into a mounted directory?

Tags: docker, nginx, webdav

This is the docker-compose for nginx

```
nginx:
container_name: nginx
image: nginx
build:
  context: ./dockerfile
  dockerfile: nginx
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: ./config/nginx/nginx.conf
    target: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  - type: bind
    source: ./config/nginx/credentials.list
    target: /etc/nginx/.credentials.list
  - type: bind
    source: /mnt/raid
    target: /webdav
```

dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx-extras libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;

include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;
    set_real_ip_from  172.0.0.0/8;
    set_real_ip_from  192.168.0.0/16;
    real_ip_header    X-Real-IP;

    gzip  on;

    server{
        server_name _;
        root /webdav;
        dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
        dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;
        dav_access user:rw group:r all:r;
        client_body_temp_path /tmp;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        create_full_put_path on;
        auth_basic realm_name;
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.credentials.list;
    }
```

`docker exec nginx ls -la /` it shows `drwxrwxr-x  12 nginx  nginx   20 Jan  4 03:01 webdav`

`docker exec nginx id -u nginx` shows `1000`

`1000` is the UID of host system user `y2kbug`. `/mnt/raid` is owned by `1000:1000`.

```
drwxrwxr-x 12 y2kbug y2kbug   20 Jan  4 11:01 raid/
```

Going into the docker container, since it is `root` user by default, the mounted directory is writable. However, connecting with WebDav, the directory is readable, but not writable. Nginx log shows these

```
2021/01/04 03:20:32 [error] 29#29: *6 mkdir() "/webdav/test" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.0.7, server: _, request: "MKCOL /test/ HTTP/1.1", host: "10.0.0.10"
10.0.0.7 - y2kbug [04/Jan/2021:03:20:32 +0000] "MKCOL /test/ HTTP/1.1" 403 143 "-" "gvfs/1.46.1" "-"
10.0.0.7 - y2kbug [04/Jan/2021:03:20:32 +0000] "PROPFIND /test HTTP/1.1" 404 143 "-" "gvfs/1.46.1" "-"
```

May I know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I have just tried changing `/mnt/raid` to `777` on host. I can create a folder via WebDav. The folder is shown `drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup    2 Jan  4 11:54  test` on host.

Answer (score 0):

adding `user nginx;` onto `nginx.conf` solved the problem.